# How to override a parent class's method with a child class's method in Java?

Tags: java, overriding

I have a task to:

> Modify the class Car so that it overrides the method setCapacity with its own version which output the message "Cannot change capacity of a car" and does not change the engine capacity.

I attempted to solve the task which the code below, but it keeps on using the `Vehicle` class's `setCapacity` method instead of the `Car` method.

```
class Vehicle // base class
{  
    int capacity;
    String make;

    Vehicle(int theCapacity, String theMake)
    {
        capacity = theCapacity;
        make = theMake;
    }

    void print() 
    {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Info:");
        System.out.println("  capacity = " + capacity + "cc" );
        System.out.println("  make = " + make );
    }

    public void setCapacity(int newCapacity)
    {
        capacity = newCapacity;
        System.out.println("New capacity = " + capacity);
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle 
{
    String type, model;

    Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel)
    {
        super(theCapacity, theMake);
        type = theType;
        model = theModel;
    }

    public void print() 
    {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("  type = " + type);
        System.out.println("  model = " + model);
    } 

    public void setCapacity()
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot change capacity of a car");
    }
}

class Task3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Car car1 = new Car(1200,"Holden","sedan","Barina");
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(1500,"Mazda");

        v1.setCapacity(1600);
        v1.print();
        car1.setCapacity(1600);
        car1.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the method signature of `setCapacity` in `Vehicle` and in `Car`. They are different. Use the `@Override` tag to notice such simple errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `setCapacity()` method of the `Car` class doesn't override the `setCapacity(int newCapacity)` method of the `Vehicle` class.

In order to override a method of the base class, the sub-class method must have the same signature.

Change

```
public void setCapacity()
{
   System.out.println("Cannot change capacity of a car");
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void setCapacity(int newCapacity)
{
   System.out.println("Cannot change capacity of a car");
}
```

Note that adding the `@Override` attribute is optional, but it will tell the compiler that you intended to override a base-class method (or implement an interface method), which will lead to a helpful compilation error if you declared the overriding method incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the class Car's method whose name is "setCapacity", it is not override its parent class Vehicle's method with the same name.Because it has not a param, but there is a param in its parent class.
Hope can help you!